# Is there some way I can track why my VS2013 ASP Web API application might be stopping?

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2013

I am running a WebAPI application on a development machine. I start the application with VS2013 in the Debug mode and then I run an E2E test which accesses application and as it goes from one screen to another the application accesses the database. When I run the test it works from start to finish about 25% of the time. The other times it hangs in different places.

The application is running as a web role on the Windows Azure dev environment on my PC.

I have tried looking at the database and there is no blocking and seems to be no problem there. Is there some way that I can get more information about what might be causing the application to suddenly stop. Here's what I see when I look at Output:

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Verbose: 500 : Role instance status check starting
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Verbose: 502 : Role instance status check succeeded: Ready
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Verbose: 500 : Role instance status check starting
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Verbose: 502 : Role instance status check succeeded: Ready
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Information: 205 : Role entrypoint . CALLING   OnStop(): WebRole1.WebRole
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Information: 205 : Role entrypoint . CALLING   OnStopping()
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Information: 206 : Role entrypoint . COMPLETED OnStop(): WebRole1.WebRole
The thread 0x4d0 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The program '[5792] WaIISHost.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[5792] WaIISHost.exe' has exited with code -66053 (0xfffefdfb).
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Information: 205 : Role entrypoint . CALLING   OnStopping()
```

Is there some way that I could get some more information about why it is hanging. What really is a problem for me is it hangs at different points of the E2E test.

I am using the Ultimate Edition of VS2013. Would IntelliTrace help me and how could I enable it?

Comment: I can't offer any help other than to suggest searching for "0xfffefdfb" and seeing if any of the problems have any bearing on your code, e.g. [Azure TCP Server - Client comunication problem](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/azure/en-US/cae78b8b-aab7-4e42-b2da-73ae5c36ddbb/azure-tcp-server-client-comunication-problem).